# Python2/Windows7: Nested Tkinter PanedWindows

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want the following nested PanedWindows to **resize correctly**.

The vertical PanedWindow should split the window in two halfs and the horizontal should split the upper pane horizontally in half. In each pane a treeview is grid. Those Treeviews have a different amount of columns and a scrollbar is attached to them.

Thanks for help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk


class Test(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createUI()
        self.mkLayout()
        self.configResize()
        self.mainloop()

    def createUI(self):
        self.paneV = ttk.PanedWindow(master=self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.paneH = ttk.PanedWindow(master=self.paneV, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.frmA = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneH)
        self.frmB = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneH)
        self.frmC = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneV)
        self.trvA = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmA,
                                 columns=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                          '8', '9', '10'))
        self.trvB = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmB, columns=('1', '2', '3'))
        self.trvC = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmC,
                                 columns=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'))
        self.scrA = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmA, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvA.xview)
        self.scrB = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmB, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvB.xview)
        self.scrC = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmC, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvC.xview)

    def mkLayout(self):
        self.trvA.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.trvB.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.trvC.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.scrA.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.scrB.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.scrC.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.paneV.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.paneH.add(self.frmA, weight=1)
        self.paneH.add(self.frmB, weight=1)
        self.paneV.add(self.paneH, weight=1)
        self.paneV.add(self.frmC, weight=1)

    def configResize(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk


class Test(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('800x600')
        self.createUI()
        self.mkLayout()
        self.configResize()
        self.mainloop()

    def createUI(self):
        self.paneV = ttk.PanedWindow(master=self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.paneH = ttk.PanedWindow(master=self.paneV, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.frmA = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneH)
        self.frmB = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneH)
        self.frmC = ttk.Frame(master=self.paneV)
        self.trvA = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmA,
                                 columns=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                          '8', '9', '10'))
        self.trvB = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmB, columns=('1', '2', '3'))
        self.trvC = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frmC,
                                 columns=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'))
        self.scrA = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmA, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvA.xview)
        self.scrB = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmB, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvB.xview)
        self.scrC = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frmC, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                  command=self.trvC.xview)
        self.trvA['xscroll'] = self.scrA.set
        self.trvB['xscroll'] = self.scrB.set
        self.trvC['xscroll'] = self.scrC.set        

    def mkLayout(self):
        self.paneV.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.paneH.add(self.frmA, weight=1)
        self.paneH.add(self.frmB, weight=1)
        self.paneV.add(self.paneH, weight=1)
        self.paneV.add(self.frmC, weight=1)
        self.trvA.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.trvB.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.trvC.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.scrA.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.scrB.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.scrC.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)


    def configResize(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmA.grid_propagate(0)
        self.frmB.grid_propagate(0)
        self.frmC.grid_propagate(0)
        self.frmA.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmB.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmC.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmA.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmB.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frmC.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Test()
```